# Riot.js: Reusing children tag names within different parent tags

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm working on a small ui project. So I developed 'form-accordion' tag that is used in following way:

```
<form-accordion>
    <panel label='panel 1'>
    ...
    </panel>
    <panel label='panel 2'>
    ...
    </panel>
</form-accordion>
```

Now I want to define another tag 'form-tabs' that I want to use in following way:

```
<form-tabs>
    <panel label='panel 1'>
    ...
    </panel>
    <panel label='panel 2'>
    ...
    </panel>
</form-tabs>
```

My question is: How to define two different tags 'panel' that will render different way under different parent tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are different ways of doing this, but basically you will define a script inside your subtag and that script receive something that indicates the change, after that, the script of panel.tag will handle your content. One way to write that code:

*file: panel.tag*

```html
<panel>
  <div>
    Your HTML here
  </div>
  
  <script>
    this.on('mount', function(){
      //write your code to handle content here
      if(opts.type == 1)
      {
         // do something
      }
      else if(opts.type == 2)
      {
         // do something else
      }
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    /* CSS class of that tag */
  </style>
</panel>
```

So when you call that tag you send something to change your content, like attribute:

*file: form-accordion.tag*

```html
<form-accordion>
  <panel type="1">
  </panel>
</form-accordion>
```

*file: form-tabs.tag*

```html
<form-tabs>
  <panel type="2">
  </panel>
</form-tabs>
```

### Another way is use better riot features like:

*file: panel.tag*

```html
<panel>
  <div>
     <div if={opts.type == 1}>
       Panel 1
     </div>
     <div if={opts.type == 2}>
       Panel 2
     </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    // 
  </script>

  <style>
    /* CSS class of that tag */
  </style>
</panel>
```

### Edit

I read again your question and perhaps simple approach fits better to your needs, that code just write your label on HTML of panel.tag:

*file: panel.tag*

```html
<panel>
  <div>
     { opts.label }
  </div>
</panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think to optimize your code, rather than call the panel tag multiple times (depending on the number of panel tags you want to see), you could create a simple loop using riot's `each` keyword to create the number of panels you want to use ... as shown below for the `form-accordion` & `form-tabs` tags. We can pass the `panelNum` in the loop as part of the tags `opts` array in an arg you called `label`

```
<form-accordion>
    <div each={panelNum in NumOfPanelsNeeded}>
        <panel label={panelNum}> ... </panel>
    </div>
</form-accordion>

<form-tabs>
    <div each={panelNum in NumOfPanelsNeeded}>
        <panel label={panelNum}> ... </panel>
    </div>
</form-tabs>
```

Then, within the famous `panel` tag, we can retrieve this `label` arg from the `opts` array and then finally display it in the tags html.

```
<panel>
    <div>panel { label }</div>

    <script>
        this.label = opts.label
    </script>
</panel>
```

Simple as that! ;)
If you need help figuring out how to add event handlers from child to parent in javascript, let me know.